# Pandas less than or equal to giving TypeError: invalid type comparison

Tags: python, pandas

I have 4 lists based on what I want to continuously filter my Pandas data-frame

```
categoryList=['Parameter1', 'Parameter1', 'Parameter2', 'Parameter2']
conditionList=['b1', 'b41', 'm1', 'm2']
conditionDescList=['>', 'btn', '<=', 'btn']
conditionParamList=['1000', '2:3', '0.5', '0.1:0.3']
```

Now I am trying below code to filter rows from my 2 data-frames(`df_custid_marker`,`df_custid_bp`) based on  `categoryList`

```
        k =0
        for i in conditionDescList:
            if(categoryList[k]=='Parameter1'):
                if(i=='btn'):
                    arrValues=conditionParamList[k].split(":")
                    minVal=arrValues[0]
                    maxVal=arrValues[1]
                    df_custid_marker=df_custid_marker[(df_custid_marker[conditionList[k]] > minVal) & (df_custid_marker[conditionList[k]] < maxVal)]
                elif(i=='>'):
                    df_custid_marker=df_custid_marker[(df_custid_marker[conditionList[k]] > conditionParamList[k])]
                elif(i=='<'):
                    df_custid_marker=df_custid_marker[(df_custid_marker[conditionList[k]] < conditionParamList[k])]
                elif(i=='<='):
                    df_custid_marker=df_custid_marker[(df_custid_marker[conditionList[k]] < conditionParamList[k]) | (df_custid_marker[conditionList[k]] == conditionParamList[k])]
                elif(i=='>='):
                    df_custid_marker=df_custid_marker[(df_custid_marker[conditionList[k]] > conditionParamList[k]) | (df_custid_marker[conditionList[k]] == conditionParamList[k])]
                else:
                    df_custid_marker=df_custid_marker[(df_custid_marker[conditionList[k]] == conditionParamList[k])]
            k+=1


        k =0
        for i in conditionDescList:
            if(categoryList[k]=='Parameter2'):
                if(i=='btn'):
                    arrValues=conditionParamList[k].split(":")
                    minVal=arrValues[0]
                    maxVal=arrValues[1]
                    df_custid_bp=df_custid_bp[(df_custid_bp[conditionList[k]] > minVal) & (df_custid_bp[conditionList[k]] < maxVal)]
                elif(i=='>'):
                    df_custid_bp=df_custid_bp[(df_custid_bp[conditionList[k]] > conditionParamList[k])]
                elif(i=='<'):
                    df_custid_bp=df_custid_bp[(df_custid_bp[conditionList[k]] < conditionParamList[k])]
                elif(i=='<='):
                    df_custid_bp=df_custid_bp[(df_custid_bp[conditionList[k]] < conditionParamList[k]) | (df_custid_bp[conditionList[k]] == conditionParamList[k])]
                elif(i=='>='):
                    df_custid_bp=df_custid_bp[(df_custid_bp[conditionList[k]] > conditionParamList[k]) | (df_custid_bp[conditionList[k]] == conditionParamList[k])]
                else:
                    df_custid_bp=df_custid_bp[(df_custid_bp[conditionList[k]] == conditionParamList[k])]
            k+=1
```

Now I am getting below error for `<=` `df_custid_marker=df_custid_marker[(df_custid_marker[conditionList[k]] < conditionParamList[k]) | (df_custid_marker[conditionList[k]] == conditionParamList[k])]`

`raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was data-frame column type was `float` and list is `string`